# How to change the structure of an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
[12] => Array
    (
        [groupID] => 19
        [groupApprovalRefID] => 123433322
        [jobrequisitionRefID] => eRS/2015/00023/021/HQ
        [groupApprovalSubject] => Principle
        [jobrequisitionGroupID] => 19
        [groupCreatedDate] => 2015-05-13 14:43:55
        [groupReference] => HQ/05/2015/016/00016
    )
```

But I need Group ID like this:

```
[19]=> Array
        (

            [groupApprovalSubject] => Principle
            [jobrequisitionGroupID] => 19
            [groupCreatedDate] => 2015-05-13 14:43:55
            [groupReference] => HQ/05/2015/016/00016
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop over each element of your array and create a new array with the indexes you want.

```
$result_array = array();

foreach ($original_array as $value)
{
    $result_array[$value['groupID']] = $value;
}
```

Note that if `groupIP` isn't unique, some values may be lost, since PHP arrays have unique indexes.

Comment: Thanks Benoit .. but i lost some datas for unique ID    [27] => Array
        (
            [groupID] => 27
            [groupApprovalRefID] => 12343
            [jobrequisitionRefID] => eRS/2015/00040/032/HQ
            [groupApprovalSubject] => Principle
            [jobrequisitionGroupID] => 27
            [groupCreatedDate] => 2015-05-13 22:00:55
            [groupReference] => HQ/05/2015/023/00023
        )

Comment: what i can do if i have unique id

Comment: @Bharath: if you have unique ids, then there's no problem. If you don't have unique ids, then you're asking something impossible.

Comment: [19]=> Array
        (array(
[0]=>
            [Job tite] => Principle
            [jobrequisitionGroupID] => 19
            [groupCreatedDate] => 2015-05-13 14:43:55
            [groupReference] => HQ/05/2015/016/00016
        ) [1]=>
            [groupApprovalSubject] => Medical
            [jobrequisitionGroupID] => 19
            [groupCreatedDate] => 2015-05-13 14:43:55
            [groupReference] => HQ/05/2015/016/00016
        ) Need Like this

Comment: @Bharath What does this mean?

Comment: EX: 19 is Grouid i want show the all details from this id but details are stored in another table.. if php mean i can work it but this is Codeginator..

Comment: is there anyone know how to convert this code from php to Codeginator?$query="select groupId from table1 where status ='1'";
$mysql_re= mysql_query($query);
while($g_id=mysql_fetch_array($mysql_re))
{

$querys="select jobId, title from table2 where jobId='.$g_id['group_id'].' status ='1'";
$mysql_res= mysql_query($querys);
while($g_ids=mysql_fetch_array($mysql_res))
{

$result[]=$g_ids;

}

}

Comment: @Bharath: you should open another question.